# Prepareforsegue not working with double?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I am trying to get an variable from my NSMutableArray to work with prepare for segue, but it is a double and i am getting an error saying 'incompatible type 'double''.

It is a masterview application.

This is what i am using

```
NSString *lonString = [weatherArray [indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"lon"];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setLon:lonString];
```

And in my detail view controller.h i am declaring the variable `@property NSString lonString`

Any ideas?

Comment: So you're weatherArray contains doubles?

Comment: does `lon` property of object in `whetherArray` array is of type `double`?

Comment: weatherArray is all my mapping results from restkit, within my weatherArray i have my model class 'Coord' which contains the double lon? does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You declared it as a string but you forgot add * to your property, you should also add a attribute, like for example:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lonString;
```

If you store NSNumber * in weatherArray (you cannot store primitive values like double) use:

```
NSString *lonString = [[weatherArray [indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"lon"] stringValue];
```

Comment: [[segue destinationViewController] setLon:lonString];    I'm still getting the error here for incompatible string for type double?

Comment: @burrGGG, In this example you pass lonString which is type of NSString* not double.

Comment: @burrGGG do you want to pass double or string? Your code and question is confused because you are talking about double and you are passing string, NSString *lonString = [weatherArray... is type of string. If you want to pass double replace it with double lonString = [[weatherArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"lon"] doubleValue]; but remember that in your destination view controller method setLon or property lon needs to be double as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
NSString *lonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[weatherArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"lon"]];
YourViewcontroller *set = [segue destinationViewController];
[set setLon:lonString];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to format your `double` value of `lon` property to be a nice string. Here is how you can do it:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3;
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
NSString *lonString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[[weatherArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"lon"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should:

```
NSString *lonString = [weatherArray [indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"lon"];
[[segue destinationViewController] setLon:[lonString doubleValue]];
```

because `objectForKey:` method returns `id` (probably `NSNumber` instance in your case) not primitive value like `double`.